# Components look terrible, no padding whatsoever

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap, create-react-app

I installed `bootstrap 3.3.7` and `react-bootstrap 0.31.5`. My `index.tsx` looks like:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button, ButtonToolbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>[...]</div>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

Where `[...]` stands in for the code [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#buttons-options).

What I would expect to happen:

[image: reference image]

What actually happens:

[image: ugly garbage]

Any clue what's going on?

Comment: I would check if you're actually importing the **v3.3.7** Stylesheet because your image that displays the problem looks as if you're using the **v4.0.0-beta.2** Stylesheet with the **v3.3.7 Theme** Stylesheet. If you do have all the correct files then you should post a [mcve] that replicates the issue (Maybe on [Codepen](https://codepen.io) since you're using TypeScript).

Comment: That was it. If you write this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The margin is come from `.btn-toolbar>.btn`. 
You should do `<div className='btn-toolbar'>[...]</div>`. If you decide to use bootstrap, you have to follow their rules strictly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the whole point of `react-bootstrap` is that it provides these for you.